# Is there a way to compress an Image?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, compressed-image-transport, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a kinect mounted on my robot, and i can view it's camera feed remotely by adding a "Image" to my rviz setup. however, it's *really* laggy. is there a way to compress the Image stream into something smaller before sending it over the wireless?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9526/is-there-a-way-to-compress-an-image?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenNI driver already uses image_transport to publish images, so you actually don't need to use republish. Assuming you have the `image_transport_plugins` stack installed, `rostopic list` should show compressed and theora versions of each image topic.

In rviz, in your Image parameters just click Transport Hints and select compressed or theora from the drop-down.

Using republish *does* make sense if you have multiple (N) subscriber nodes on the other side. If they all subscribe to the compressed topic, then you decompress each image N times. Better to do the decompression once in a republish node, and pipe the raw output to the N subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4